# Saving streams of data to MongoDB using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, twitter, stream

I have managed to stream tweets from the Twitter Streaming API and I was wondering how to auto insert it in my collection in MongoDB? Here's the code I have so far. It only stores it in a JS file but I want it to be auto inserted in my collection.

```
var TwitterStream = require('twitter-stream-api'),
fs = require('fs');

var keys = {
consumer_key : "xxxx",
consumer_secret : "xxxx",
token : "xxxx",
token_secret : "xxxx"
};

var Twitter = new TwitterStream(keys, false);
Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {
track: 'travel'
});

Twitter.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('final_tweets_asd.json'));
```

UPDATE

I've read a question similar to mine and have updated my code Tweets insertion into mongodb via nodejs. Here's what I've done:

```
var Twitter = new TwitterStream(keys, false);
Twitter.stream('statuses/filter', {
track: 'travel'
}, function (stream) {
stream.on('data', function (data) {
console.log(data);
console.log("\n\n\n\n");
db.tweets.findAndModify({
    query: {'id': 'data.id'},
    update: { $set: data},
    upsert: true,
    new: true
})
});
});
```

The code runs but it does not store it in MongoDB. Also Im a bit confused with the solution. From what I can remember, you need to specify the db name and the collection name to be able to insert. "db.tweets.findAndModify" only provides the database name.

Comment: What is your collection `tweets` schema ?

Comment: Forgive me but i'm new. What do you mean by the tweets schema? I only have the dbname as `insert_sample`, collection as `sample_collection`. As for the tweets, it is not always the same since there are some tweets that dont contain pictures/coordinates.

Comment: Are you using any specific node package to manage mongodb read/writes such as mongoose ?? Do share your connection code for mongo that you are using on nodejs

Comment: No. Nothing, just the `twitter-stream-api` and the `fs`. I'm really sorry to be a bother as im very new to these platforms. @RagZ

Comment: Would recommend you to follow this [tutorial](http://www.jenniferbland.com/saving-data-to-mongodb-database-from-node-js-application-tutorial/) instead.

Comment: I've been to that tutorial and it needs a schema. Problem with mine is that each tweet collected does not always have the same schema.

Comment: You can just have a schema that accepts `Schema.Types.Mixed` so that you can store the whole object thats returned from twitter api

Comment: @RagZ Okay I've looked into the tutorial again. It only needs the dbname `mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/node-demo");`. How do I specify the collection name?

Comment: var tweetCollection = db.collection("tweetsCollectionName");

Comment: also there is an error at line  `query: {'id': 'data.id'},` to get record by id you should use like `query: {"_id": data.id}` - in single-qoute it's a string, and if your data.id is string value of ObjectId, you need to cast explicitly to it like `require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId(data.id)`